# Assembler and c++ output text

Tags: c++, assembly

How can I display text with assembler in c++ code? I want to make a function with a parameter the string which will be displayed.

Comment: You want to embed inline assembly inside your C++ code to display a string? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Which assembler? Does it provide any basic IO library for your target platform? Which target platform? Note that when you write assembly, all notion of cross-platform things like `printf` are discarded. You will need to call platform-specific APIs to write to the console. For example in Windows, `WriteFile`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia does it really matters WHY he wants to do it?

Comment: @Luchian: it was out of curiosity and to double check that I correctly understood the question (it wasn't completely clear).

Answer (score 1):

In the assembler you can make the appropriate system calls to read or write. Your OS will have a description of the supported system calls, and generally there is some sort of operation (eg interrupt 80h or sys call instruction) to make a system call.

Without more details (eg operating system or hardware) that's as specific as I can get.

Comment: can you give me some example please?

Comment: @JordanBorisov what os / system / compiler are you using?  for example, MSVC has different syntax from GCC

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write a sample application with a `prinf` in it and look at the compiled code. In VS you can easily do this while debugging, just go to "Show dissasembly". Not sure how you would do it under *nix, but I'm pretty sure it's doable.

Comment: I try to debug but only assembler part which I saw was in the chkstk.asm

Comment: What system/compiler are you using?

Comment: I see VS2010... while debugging, right click on the code and select "Show dissasembly".